# capserjs utils.dump logging "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, testing, logging, casperjs

I have this in my Client Side code:

```
console.log('login', S.loginData)
```

and this in my casperjs test

```
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    utils.dump(msg)
})
```

the console output is always:

```
"login [object Object]"
```

How can I log the object properly?

Comment: What does the `console.log` statement have to do with the `casper.on` statement?

Comment: Sorry. I made a copypasta mistake.

Using the "remote.message" event casperjs pipes remote console.log to stdout.

I would use util.inspect for deeper loggin, but this is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly fine behavior since `console.log('login', S.loginData)` in the page context produces one string. Contrary to developer tools like the one in Chrome, an object cannot be inspected after it is logged. It must be converted directly into a printable format. If `S.loginData` doesn't have a `toString` function, it will be printed as `[object Object]`.

If you want the properties of `S.loginData` excluding functions, you could try

```
console.log('login', JSON.stringify(S.loginData));
```

in the page context (your page). If you cannot change this line, then you could try to proxy `console.log` like this somewhere at the beginning of the navigation/initilization:

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    var oldlog = console.log;
    console.log = function(){
        var fixedArgs = arguments.map(function(arg){
            return JSON.stringify(arg);
        });
        oldlog.apply(console, fixedArgs);
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this clears up much! So if an Object has a toString Function it gets called automatically?

Comment: Yes, at least in current Chrome. Since PhantomJS 1.x is comparable to Chrome 13, I suspect it works.